# Complete compatible replacement of System.IO.Stream as an extension

Tags: c#, service, io, stream

I need to make a file transfer using a service wrapping the actual stream and decided to make it happen as a complete compatible `System.IO.Stream` replacement, overriding all methods and properties. I intend to use it as a regular stream with the service in the middle doing the **IO**. Is there a life cycle documentation of the `IO.Stream` I can base on? I coudn't find it, maybe I'm using the wrong keywords.

Comment: Life cycle???  Replacement?  You didn't replace anything, System.IO.Stream is an abstract class.

Comment: Hans, as an abstract the implementation may leave some methods or properties to the base implementation. I need a all new implementation fully compatible with IO.Stream but working only with my service solution. I asked about life cycle to know when to value each property while runing my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the basics as found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Notes to Implementers
>
> When you implement a derived class of Stream, you must provide implementations for the Read and Write methods. The asynchronous methods ReadAsync, WriteAsync, and CopyToAsync use the synchronous methods Read and Write in their implementations. Therefore, your implementations of Read and Write will work correctly with the asynchronous methods.
>
> The default implementations of ReadByte and WriteByte create a new single-element byte array, and then call your implementations of Read and Write. When you derive from Stream, we recommend that you override these methods to access your internal buffer, if you have one, for substantially better performance. You must also provide implementations of CanRead, CanSeek, CanWrite, Flush, Length, Position, Seek, and SetLength.
>
> Do not override the Close method, instead, put all the Stream cleanup logic in the Dispose method.

Comment: Thanks, Chris! Thats exactly the sort of info I was looking for.
I didn't notice the Notes to Implementers section. Will stay tuned for that from now on.